# Amazon RDS - How to Create new DB using PHP API?

Tags: amazon-rds

In a SAAS app, written in PHP, how to create a new mysql database in an existing RDS instance?

The documentation for php api here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-rds.html

doesn't show any such function available under available operations section at the bottom.

How do we do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option provided in [RDS API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html). When you call [CreateDBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html) API, you can specify the `DBName` but that is at the time of creating a new RDS instance. Once you have created the instance, then there is no provision to create a new DB on it.

I would imagine you need to connect via PHP using ODBC (or whatever that PHP supports) to the RDS endpoint and then create a new DB just like you are connecting to a non-RDS remote DB.